# Insert datetime from C# to SqlSrv

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to save in the database a date field type "datetime" from C# using EntityFramework.

In MySql works fine but no in Sqlsrv.

The idea is that the system can work with MySql or SqlSrv, that's why I use datetime and not datetime2.

My model:

```
public partial class Entity: ITimeStamp
{
    
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
.......
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("entities");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Name, "entities_name_unique")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .HasColumnName("id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("created_at");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
                .HasColumnName("name");

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasColumnName("updated_at");
        });
......
}
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is ITimeStamp && (
                e.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((ITimeStamp)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((ITimeStamp)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My Controller:

```
var entity = new Entity
{
    Name = installer.CompanyName,
    ...
};
_context.Entities.Add(entity);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Exception:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I tried setting the fields to nullable, but instead of throwing an exception it doesn't save any date.

Comment: Also another thought. Are your datetimes nullable in DB? if so then perhaps do a .Value at the end of the DateTime variables will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the default value for a `DateTime` instance in .NET is `0001-01-01T00:00:00` (ISO8601 notation). In Sql Server the range of a DateTime is limited and must be greater than `1753-1-1T00:00:00` (also ISO8601 notation). You must specify a value of your `DateTime` instance that is greater than this date.

An alternative is to use a Nullable DateTime? instance and make the column value accept nulls in your DB schema so that a lack of value results in a NULL value in the database.

If you are sure that you are setting the values correctly before the save you should profile the operation using Sql Profiler and see what the value is that is being passed and causing the Exception. It could be that the name of the column does not correspond with the name of the schema column or that there is another column in the database that is not mapped back to your entity.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post: I tried setting the fields to nullable, but instead of throwing an exception it doesn't save any date.

Comment: @xSkArx - As I mentioned you need to use a profiler or debug the code to see what is then actually being passed. I believe you are not actually setting the value at all and the default value is being used (null or default value of DateTime depending on if it is nullable or not). Once you debug your code you will be able to see that and hopefully start to understand why your value is not being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my projects. Below is the code I have and it is working perfectly fine in over 10 projects. Below is my DbContext

```
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //This allows the audit fields to automatically be added, or updated.
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        var state = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x.State).ToList();

        state.ForEach(x => {

            switch(x)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    UpdateAddedEntity();
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    UpdateModifiedEntity();
                    break;
            }

        });

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Update Entity Pattern
    protected void UpdateAddedEntity()
    {
        var created = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).Select(e => e.Entity).ToArray();

        foreach (var entity in created)
        {
            if (entity is AuditFields)
            {
                var auditFields = entity as AuditFields;
                auditFields.CreateDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                auditFields.ModifiedDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                auditFields.Active = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void UpdateModifiedEntity()
    {
        //Modified record changes
        var modified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(e => e.Entity).ToArray();

        foreach (var entity in modified)
        {
            if (entity is AuditFields)
            {
                var auditFields = entity as AuditFields;
                auditFields.ModifiedDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
```

Oh I guess if you want the model for my audit fields here that is too:

```
public class AuditFields
    {
        protected AuditFields()
        {
            Active = true;
            CreateDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ModifiedDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [IndexColumn]
        public DateTime CreateDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [IndexColumn]
        public DateTime ModifiedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

        [IndexColumn]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: does this work in sqlsrv for you? It only works in MySql for me

Comment: Yes. I've used it for SQL Server and MySQL. My DateTime fields in SQL are datetime2(7). Is that what yours are? And the fields are Non-nullable. I added a picture of my fields in sql server

Comment: I use datetime for both, because the user can select which type of database to use. The problem is that in MySql there is no datetime2

Comment: Correct. Datetime2 is a term used in MS SQL Server. A MS SQL Server column defined as datetime2(6) is the equivalent to a MySQL 5.7 datetime or timestamp column. So you can change to a datetime2(6), or you will have to modify the datetime to adhere to column constraints in mysql

Answer (score 0):

After many test, finally I solve my problem.

I remove the datetime definition from DBContext and leave it in the model definition, so that EF decides which type of datetime to choose for the DB type chosen by the client.